# Error with OpenSSL commands when run as a part of CMake Build

Tags: cmake, openssl

I am trying to generate self signed certificates using openSSL as part of internal feature testing. The intention is to have new certs (short lived) generated for every round of testing.

For the build procedure I have added custom targets to my CMakeLists.txt like so:

```
add_custom_target(ca_rsa
    COMMAND mkdir -p ${INSTALL_LOCATION}/security_context/ca/cert
    COMMAND mkdir -p ${INSTALL_LOCATION}/security_context/ca/private
    COMMAND ${OPENSSL} req -nodes -x509 -days 30 -text -sha256 -newkey
    rsa:2048 -keyout ${INSTALL_LOCATION}/security_context/ca/private/rsa_key.pem
    -out ${INSTALL_LOCATION}/security_context/ca/cert/rsa_cert.pem
    -config ./openssl_rsa.cnf)
```

ca_rsa is added as a dependency for the target executable for the project.

When I run the build I get the following error :

```
/bin/sh: req not found
recipe for target ca_rsa failed
```

I tried running the command by itself and it works fine.

Edit:

${OPENSSL} is set as follows:

```
set(OPENSSL ${OPENSSL_INSTALL_LOCATION}/bin/openssl)
```

Comment: It smells like `OPENSSL` variable is not set, so `COMMAND ${OPENSSL} req -nodes -x509 -days 30 -text -sha256 -newkey` tries to execute `req`, which is wrong.

Comment: I should have added that part too. Apologies! Just updated the question.

Comment: If you use `make` for build the project, add `VERBOSE=1` option for it. Such way complete command lines will be printed before executing. You may check content of the command line of your interest, and even copy-paste it and try to run alone.